# Equivalent for DataOutputStream of Java in Objective C

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, dataoutputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I am currently working on a Project which is in Objective C.

I need to use Functions of Java class `DataOutputStream` like `writeChars`, `writeLong`, `flush` and some functions of `ByteArrayOutputStream` Class.

Specifically, what can I use in Objective C which has the same functionality as the `DataOutputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` class?

This is the code i need to convert into Objective C.

```
public static byte[] getByteArray(String key, long counter) throws IOException
{

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    if (key != null)
    {
        dos.writeChars(key);
    }
    dos.writeLong(counter);
    dos.flush();
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I would use writeUTF to write a string, it's likely to more efficient and easier to decode.

Comment: @Rahul: Kindly inform if it worked or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog();
```

the above method takes string  and objects as arguments.
As,

`NSLog(@"Hi this is demo of string printing.");`

`NSLog(@"Hi this is integer %d",intValue);//this is like printf isnt it?`

EDIT:

Either %b, or convert it into NSData object and then print using %@. Obj-c uses %@ for all kind of object.

```
unsigned int a = 0x000000FF;
NSLog(@"%x", a);//prints the most significant digits first
```

Comment: What is the equivalent for binary data?

Comment: `DataOutputStream` is for binary data in Big Endian only.  The question is; what is the equivalent in Objective-C

Comment: Either %b, or convert it into NSData object and then print using %@. Obj-c uses %@ for all kind of object.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is convert primitive data types into raw bytes.

```
NSMutableData* dataBuffer = [NSMutableData data]; //obj-c byte array

long long number = 123456LL; //note that long long is needed in obj-c to represent 64bit numbers
NSData* numberData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&number length:sizeof(number)]; 
[dataBuffer appendData:numberData];

NSString* text = @"abcdefg";
const char* rawText = [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //java uses utf8 encoding
NSData* textData = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawText length:strlen(rawText)];
[dataBuffer appendData:textData];

return dataBuffer;
```

No `flush()` is necessary (I believe in Java is not neccessary with `ByteArrayOutputStream` either)

This is a bit simplified, note that when Java writes a string, the first two bytes are always the string length. Java also writes numbers in Big Endian. We are writing them in system byte-order. That shouldn't be a problem if you don't want to send the binary data to other devices.

You can switch byte order using utilities in `CFByteOrderUtils.h` or you can get the number in Big Endian directly by the following:

```
- (NSData*)bytesFromLongLong:(long long)number {
    char buffer[8];

    for (int i = sizeof(buffer) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        buffer[i] = (number & 0xFF);
        number >> 8; 
    }

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:sizeof(buffer)]
}
```